# Is Center-Surround mechanism implemented in opencv?

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching, feature-detection, image-recognition, edge-detection

I am new to the concept of Biologically Salient Regions Detector, and I read some papers and they always use the mechanism of `Center-Surrond` to computer features intensity, color and orientation. I googled that mechanism but i did not find implementation of it by `Opencv` with `Java` API or in any other libraries.

Actually i want to create the saliency map, and as far as i researched, some features like intensity, color, orientation are to be computed by the center-surround mechanism/filter.

I read lot o publications and the best of them, just provided a pseudo code but still it lacks clarity. i mean if you have a question regarding detailed issues to have an idea how that filter works, that pseudo code would not help much.

Is the center-surround filter mechanism is implemented in `Opencv` or in any other library?

Please provide explanation using and pseudocode.

Comment: are you not able to implement the center-surround mechanism/filter or do you not understand what it is (in detail)?

Comment: @Micka sorry for the late reply. it is about the how that mechanism works.. i got a puplication that explains in peseudo code how to compute the on-off intensity..but mentioned nothing about the off-on intensity..so i just need to know how it works because it will be applied also on the color and orientation

Answer (score 4):

These links may point you in the right direction I hope.

http://www.cs.rit.edu/~rlc/Dissertation/chapter6color.pdf

http://ilab.usc.edu/publications/doc/Itti_Koch00vr.pdf

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MkSY6pFhmYsC&pg=PA540&lpg=PA540&dq=center-surround+filter+mechanism&source=bl&ots=vVbCv_Ilou&sig=aU18i3J4agHVplK8u9psZ_TySks&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tnQ2VeWGHoTmao-xgdgG&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=center-surround%20filter%20mechanism&f=false

And [this](http://www.tatome.de/fileadmin/code/saliency.py) link it to an early version of Itti and Koch's saliency model in Pythons OpenCV bindings.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding towards ON - OFF channels in Vision, I would suggest you to have look into this excellent research aiming **To determine how visual perception is processed by the brain and how visually guided eye movements are generated** which is carried at Schiller MIT [The Function of the On and Off Channels in Vision](http://web.mit.edu/bcs/schillerlab/research/A-Vision/A7-1.html).

Detailed explanations along with examples and source code is available [here](http://matlabserver.cs.rug.nl/cgi-bin/matweb.exe) for

- Center Surround cell responses.
- Dot Pattern selective cell.
- Spot-Group detection
- Spot detection

Hope it helps